# How to get current year dayname of birthday's who having in current week from date of birth column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get week name(sunday,monday,...etc) of people who having birthday in current week from date of birth column from employee table in mysql.  i need in which day there birthday will fall on current year

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do something like this using just MySQL alone. If you're using PHP or another server-side language, you could just query the relevant information (DOB, Name) from the database, and then use that to create your list.

Comment: i did that with this query SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS Name ,DOB,
DayName(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DOB,INTERVAL (YEAR(now()) - YEAR(DOB)) YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d')) `Birthday`
FROM tbi_Customer_Details
WHERE month(DOB) = month(curdate()) 
AND weekofyear(DOB) = weekofyear(curdate())